# create new array from 2 other arrays

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays that contain user details, including emails addresses. I would like to create a new array that contain only the user details where email that appear in both arrays. is there any function that do that?

I tried to use "array_intersect_assoc". no good...

```
$newGroupsArray = array_intersect ($firstArray , $secondArray  );
```

for instance, - in this example only "nathalie" details should be in the new array.
Is there any function that do that?

```
$firstArray = array( 0 => Array ( 'name' => 'ronen',    'email' => 'ronen$Experts.com' ,    'contactID' => 43 ) ,
                1 => Array ( 'name' => 'shlomig' ,  'email' => 'shlomig$tours.co.il' ,'contactID' => 28 ) ,
                2 => Array ( 'name' => 'nathalie',  'email' => 'nathalie$obra.co.il',   'contactID' => 57 ) 

         );
$secondArray  = array(0 => Array ( 'name' => 'nathalie',    'email' => 'nathalie$obra.co.il',   'contactID' => 57 ) ,
                        1 => Array ('name' => 'roi' ,       'email' => 'roi$mail.com' ,'contactID' => 99 ) 
         );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine array_values and array_intersect_key to get desired result.

```
$Array1 = array();

$Array2 = array();

foreach ($firstArray as $value) 
{
    $Array1[$value['email']] = $value;
}   

foreach ($secondArray as $value) 
{
    $Array2[$value['email']] = $value;
}   

$matches = array_values(array_intersect_key($Array1, $Array2));

print_r($matches);
```

You can also use foreach loops and check the data using an if condition as below.

```
$matches = array();
foreach($firstArray as $key => $value)
{
    foreach($secondArray as $value1)
    {
        if($value['email'] === $value1['email'])
            $matches[] = $value;
    }   
}

print_r($matches);
```